# Selenium Webdriver runs in root but not in non-root account

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have this problem that when I run in root account it works properly with the test cases returning the expected. But in non-root account it keep giving me error. Thanks in advance if you are helping me out.

What I had done:
- Use selenium IDE to export into test case in JUnit Webdriver
- Mavenized and execute the test.
- This server is Ubuntu 12.04
- xvfb is used for virtual display buffer

Maven file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ncs</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>IntegrationTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error is as below:

---

### Test set: TestGoogle

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 33.153 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGoogle(TestGoogle)  Time elapsed: 33.137 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Gmail"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.03 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-51-generic-pae', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
Session ID: 524ff8d4-1ea3-4421-b9c1-ae1c34d8fd66
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=25.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at TestGoogle.testGoogle(TestGoogle.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Gmail"}
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-51-generic-pae', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///tmp/anonymous5771616614386270554webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8880)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///tmp/anonymous5771616614386270554webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)
```